# How can I determine whether a cv::Mat is using internal or external data?

Tags: c++, opencv, memory-management, mat

I'm integrating OpenCV with a legacy codebase that has its own ref-counted image class.  I'm adding a constructor for creating these images from cv::Mat.  As an optimization, I'd like to exploit cv::Mat's refcounting mechanism & make a shallow copy, when it owns the data.  However, when it's using external data, then I need to force a deep copy.

The problem is that, from reading the docs, I don't see a way to determine whether a cv::Mat owns its data or not.  Can this be done (without modifying OpenCV)?

BTW, in case it matters, I'm using OpenCV 3.1.

Comment: did you have a look at the constructor or destructor code of cv::Mat how they decide whether the Mat holds internal or external data?

Comment: I stared at mat.hpp, matrix.cpp, and umatrix.cpp long enough to appreciate their complexity.

Comment: What I missed was opencv2/core/mat.inl.hpp.  I thought some inline functions were probably hiding somewhere.

Comment: @Micka: it's from this question and your comment that I think I probably know what's the definition of *external data*: the data where OpenCV is not responsible for its refcounting. Am I correct?

Comment: @Micka: Btw I'm trying to read all tutorials provided by OpenCV.org, is this the most efficient way to learn OpenCV? I'm a newbie to OpenCV(I use version 4.4.0) and I just want to "draw a histogram" and "understand why it does so" but I can't. I cannot understand the `calcHist` so I decided to read through all tutorial modules from the start...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the member `UMatData * u` of cv::Mat. It should be 0 if cv::Mat uses external data, otherwise you can get the ref counter as follows

```
img.u->refcount
```